# Regular Expression For URL after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have scenario where i want to validate some malicious script. I want that whenever the URL gets something which  starts like `<~script>` Then it should redirect to Error page.

Search code:-

```
dv.RowFilter = "Description LIKE ('%" + Request.QueryString["tx"].Trim().ToLower() + "%') or Title LIKE ('%" + Request.QueryString["tx"].Trim().ToLower() + "%')";
    dv.Sort = "Title ASC";
    dgrdPages.DataSource = dv;
    dgrdPages.DataBind();
    lblSearchWords.Text = Request.QueryString["tx"].ToString();
    lblFilesFound.Text = dv.Count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python

```
import re
text = 'http://localhost:54149/RBLBank/search.aspx?tx=test<~script>'
text2='http://localhost:54149/RBLBank/search.aspx?tx=test'
m = re.search('(<~script>.*)', text)
n = re.search('(<~script>.*)', text2)
if m:
    found = m.group(1)
    print found," found"
else:
    print "URL is safe"

if n:
    found = n.group(1)
    print found," found"
else:
    print "URL is safe"
```

Comment: where you want to apply validation their you can apply

Comment: I am not into C# or ASP.Net. 
But i am sure there will be a part where you give a if condition to check <~script> is present or not. There you can do a preg_match(PHP terminology change to whatever ASP is providing) If it is true then you have the script in ur URL

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat: It is giving error as `Unrecognised space`

Comment: Can you give me some input data. You are trying? And the output you need.
   eg: Input : http://<~script>..... Output:0 or 1

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat: See this my URL `http://localhost:54149/RBLBank/search.aspx?tx=test` after test when I enter `<~script>` then it should give error

Comment: I have written a small script in Python. You can use the same logic

    import re
    text = 'http://localhost:54149/RBLBank /search.aspx?tx=test<~script>'
    text2='http://localhost:54149/RBLBank/search.aspx?tx=test' 
    m = re.search('(<~script>.*)', text)
    n = re.search('(<~script>.*)', text2)
    if m:
        found = m.group(1)
        print found," found"
   else:
       print "URL is safe"

    if n:
      found = n.group(1)
      print found," found"
    else:
       print "URL is safe"

Comment: Please format the code. 4 space was not working in comment i guess
https://gist.github.com/9af56d66b40fb20813fe.git
You can see the code here

Comment: I want that in `asp.net`  Also, I am unable to format

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code


ASP.Net i am not good at and now I dont have the IDE to do that. What other programming language you know?
PHP,C? or scripting JS?